# Ruby SAVON gem errors in making request

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

I'm trying to make what appears to be a pretty straight forward `SOAP` request, one that works in `SoapUI` but when I execute my **Ruby** code, I get a 'raise_soap_and_http_errors!' Exception executing request.

Here's the code - the document referenced in **wsdl_path** works in **SOAPUI** to make the authenticate request.

```
require 'savon'
wsdl_path = 'XXXX_soap_interface.wsdl'

client = Savon.client(
  :wsdl => wsdl_path,
  :ssl_verify_mode => :none,
  :raise_errors => true, # false if you don't want to see exceptions
  pretty_print_xml: true)



response = client.call( 

:authenticate, 
message: {:partnerName => 'XXXX', :userName => 'xxxxxx', :password => 'xxxxx'}
)
puts response
```

The error I get back is:

```
savon/response.rb:85:in `raise_soap_and_http_errors!': (SOAP-
ENV:Server) Exception executing request (Savon::SOAPFault)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-2.4.0/lib/savon/response.rb:14:in `initialize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-2.4.0/lib/savon/operation.rb:64:in `new'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-2.4.0/lib/savon/operation.rb:64:in `create_response'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-2.4.0/lib/savon/operation.rb:55:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/savon-2.4.0/lib/savon/client.rb:36:in `call'
        from xxx_soap.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

I'm running Ruby 1.9, anyone have any ideas on what would make this work?

edit:  The wsdl_path variable, when used to create the Savon client, works.  I'm able to create the client and also execute client.operations and successfully get back the operations from the SOAP service.  Only the request is failing.

edit:  After adding the helpful logging code from below, I am getting this back:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:common="urn:xxx-com:cloud:common"
    xmlns:finsvc="urn:xxx-com:cloud:finsvc"
    xmlns:finsvc-13-6-0="urn:xxx-com:cloud:finsvc:13.6.0">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
      <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Exception executing request</faultstring>
      <detail>
        <operationResult>
          <errorCode>101</errorCode>
          <errorMessage>SOAP error 44 (SOAP 1.1 fault: SOAP-ENV:Client [no subcode] "Validation constraint violation: occurrence v
iolation in element 'userName'" Detail: [no detail] )</errorMessage>
        </operationResult>
      </detail>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

No matter what order I put the parameters in or if I use camelcase or not, the first parameter specified in message throws the above error.

Answer (score 2):

Switch on logging with

```
client = Savon.client(
...
log: true,
loglevel: :debug,
pretty_print_xml: true)
```

and share the output if you can't find the problem.

If the problem still exists then you should go the standard way:

1. Get SoapUI
2. create a valid call which you can execute successfully
3. based on that - write a Ruby script (not Ruby on Rails!!) which creates a valid request
4. integrate that code into your Rails (or whatever project).

Comment: Thanks, I was having a hard time outputting to the console what was going on.  I added your suggested code, and it looks like the request is failing on the parameters themselves somehow _ I added the error output to my question...

Answer (score 1):

So this all turned out to be issues in the wsdl document where fields that were required were not stated as so, but the response from the service did not reveal this.

Answer (score 0):

`wsdl_path` should be a full URL, like `http://domain.name/.../soap.wsdl`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your statement here isn't accurate.  wsdl_path can also point to a local file, which is what it's doing here.  Like I said, the wsdl file referenced by that variable works in SOAP UI, and the client connection using the wsdl variable works to, so for example, I can create the client, and I can then use client.operations and get back the list of operations from the SOAP service.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The error you got is a SOAPFault, rather than a HTTP error.